# How to get top and left postion of child element of Group container from IDML file

Tags: idml

I am extracting data from IDML find and calculation top and left of element and place it to canvas.
It is working fine with element who are not under any group.
But for group container i am not getting proper X and Y position.

I had gone through cookbook of IDML and set logic accordingly but i am not getting correct X and Y.

I had also try solution given in below link

https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/converting-a-rotated-text-from-idml-to-html5/m-p/4435789